# Twitter data mining for a specific user (python)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to setup a bot, which will read tweets from a twitter user and store. I can find several examples on search for particular key words, post ID etc.

Can any one recommend which api call is required for monitoring one particular user?

Answer (score 0):

use tweepy for data mining from twitter https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API call you would use is `statuses/user_timeline`. The documentation is [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Some python examples to get you started with using Twitter are [here](http://geduldig.github.io/TwitterAPI/examples.html).